# How to use reshape in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to reshape pixel intensity by imagesize*1(column vector).

```
Imvect = reshape(I,imsize,1);
```

But why these error comes?

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

Comment: `imsize` must have the same number of elements than `I`

Comment: Hi! Did the answer help solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer. =)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the syntax used in the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
B = reshape(A,sz1,...,szN)
```

What `reshape` does is to take the matrix `A`, straightens it out, and gives it a new size, that's determined by the 2nd, 3rd to the Nth argument. For this to be possible, you need to have the same number of elements in the input matrix as you have in the output matrix. You can't make a 1x5 vector turn into a 2x3 vector, as one element would be missing. The number of elements in the output matrix will be proportional to the product of `sz1, sz2, ..., szN`. Now, if you know you want N rows, but don't know exactly how many columns you have, you might use the `[]` syntax, that tells MATLAB to use as many columns as necessary to make the number of elements be equal.

So `reshape(A, 2, [], 3)` will become a 2xNx3 matrix, where, for a matrix with 24 elements, N will be 4.

Now, in your case this is not the case. `numel(I) ~= imsize`. If `mod(numel(I), imsize) ~= 0` then your `imsize` is definitely incorrect. However, if `mod(numel(I), imsize) == 0`, then your error might be that you want `imsize` number of rows, and a number of columns that makes this possible. If it's the latter, then this should work:

```
Imvect = reshape(I,imsize, []);
```

If you simply want to make you matrix `I` a vector of size `(numel(I), 1)`, then you should use the [colon operator](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)  `:`, as such:

```
Imvect = I(:);
```

An alternative, if you really want to use `reshape`, is to specify that you want a single column, and let MATLAB select the number of rows, as such:

```
Imvect = reshape(I, [], 1);
```